# how it affects one array to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
-(IBAction)Done :(id) sender {

    NSMutableArray *addinfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; 

    AddinfoCarteV *addinfoCarteV =[[AddinfoCarteV alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddinfoCarteV" bundle:nil]; 
    [addinfo addObject:textfieldToAdd.text]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",addinfo); 
    addinfoCarteV.informationMan = addinfo ; 
    textfieldToAdd.hidden= NO ; 
}
```

Comment: NSMutableArray *informationMan ;

Comment: addinfoCarteV.informationMan = addinfo ;

Comment: How could you say "the assignment does not work " Are you getting crash ?

Comment: No no crash but i have a tableview in AddinfoCarteV and i want to add addinfo in this tableView

Comment: Please ask complete questions. Edit the question and don't throw in just another statement in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to ask questions clearly..I think you need to allocate and initialize your `addinfoCarteV.informationMan` array.or if you want to copy your `addinfo` array to   `informationMan` array  try this code

```
addinfoCarteV.informationMan = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[addinfoCarteV.informationMan addObjectsFromArray:addinfo];
```